# How does Xpath in groovy to return Tags and Values

Tags: xpath, groovy, tags, soapui

I have the following XML, and in SOAPUI Groovy I am attempting go capture a set of  XML with its tags and values, for example:

```
<telephoneNumbers>
    <telephone>
        <id>125042741</id>
        <areaCode>0161</areaCode>
        <phoneNumber>4804420</phoneNumber>
        <extension>1234</extension>
        <usage>Work</usage>
    </telephone>
</telephoneNumbers>
```

im trying to return to following outcome (tags and values):

```
<telephone>
    <id>125042741</id>
    <areaCode>0161</areaCode>
    <phoneNumber>4804420</phoneNumber>
    <extension>1234</extension>
    <usage>Work</usage>
</telephone>
```

Here is the groovy:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )  
def Recall = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "Recall#Response" ) 

def telephone = Recall[ "//telephone//*" ] as String
String returnXml = ""

if ( Recall["//restrict"] !=  null ) {
    returnXml= telephone
}
else 
    return returnXml
```

Comment: what does your groovy code return?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this answer [How do I print a groovy Node with namespace preserved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227447/how-do-i-print-a-groovy-node-with-namespace-preserved/5012799#5012799) you could parse the Xml using XmlSlurper and afterwards print the xml nodes you wish to with StreamingMarkupBuilder.

```
String xml = Recall.getXml()
def telephoneNumbers = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)​​​​​​​​
def outputBuilder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
String telephoneXml = outputBuilder.bind { mkp.yield telephoneNumbers.telephone }
```

I posted a runnable example here: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/1245001 not using SOAPUI but a simple string for demonstration. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your code returns the including the tag, how to retrieve only the value inside the tag ?